# Mongodb/Mongoose: Storing Subdocument of a Variable to a Variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a shotgun npm command for deleting all topics ever created by a user

This is a sample user entry (users are stored in a collection called 'users'):

```
{
"__v" : 0,
"_id" : ObjectId("536c4c8fafec055606f01840"), //the id I want to store to a variable and use the variable to find all topics with that id in the 'creator' document
"joinDate" : ISODate("2014-05-09T18:13:28.079Z"),
"lastActiveDate" : ISODate("2014-05-09T18:13:48.918Z"),
"lastSocketId" : null,
"password" : "Johndoe6",
"roles" : [],
"username" : "johndoe6"
}
```

This is a sample topic entry (topics are stored in a collection called 'topics'):

```
{
"__v" : 4,
"_id" : 202, //unreliable as these change all the time
"body" : "example topic text",
"commentCount" : 0,
"creator" : ObjectId("536c4c8fafec055606f01840"), //this is the id I want to be found with my variable from a found user
"date" : ISODate("2014-05-14T13:58:13.668Z"),
"editedBy" : ObjectId("536f0392ca01fb0e39364c02"),
"editedDate" : ISODate("2014-05-14T13:59:27.607Z"),
"lastCommentDate" : ISODate("2014-05-14T13:58:13.670Z"),
"tags" : [],
"title" : "test",
"views" : [],
}
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
exports.invoke = function (shell, options) {
if (!options.confirm) {
    shell.warn("Are you sure you want to delete all topics made by {{0}}? (Y/N)".format(options.username));
    return shell.setPrompt('confirm', 'purgeTopic', options, 'Are you sure?');
}
shell.db.User.findOne({ username: options.username }, function (err, user) {
var userid = something //this is where I want it to pluck out the user's ID and store it for later

    if (err) return shell.error(err);
    if (!user) return shell.error("No user {{0}} exists.".format(options.username));
    //otherwise
    shell.db.Topic.where('creator').equals(userid).remove(function (err) {
```

As you can see, options.username is a variable that has been typed in by the user doing the command. On the last line I want it to remove topics that have a subdocument 'creator' with the id of the 'user'. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

It would simply be:

```
var userid = user._id;
```

But you'd want to put that after your `if (!user)` check in case `user` is `null`.

Comment: this does not pull the actual user id from the user id and is undefined

Comment: @user3630558 Does your schema defined for `User` match up with the user doc you're searching for?  Them not matching is the only way I know of for that to happen.